# a problem about Inequality zoom

Tags: analysis

[image]

I came across this inequality. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you need exactly? Do you want to prove it? If yes, what methods have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

The terms are monotonically decreasing, so compare this via the integral test. Also use the fact that $\log(n)<\log(x)$ for $x>n$.

Comment: Can you flesh our more details? What function are you integrating?

Comment: It works.Thanks a lot!